# How to create a cocos2dx-3.0 project in xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I downloaded cocos-2dx 3.0rc and run "setup.py". READ.ME tells that we can use "cocos new" to create a project and "cocos run" to run a project. However, I tried to use xcode to create a new project but I find there is no xcode templates. How can I use xcode to develop cocos2dx-3.0 projects?

Answer (score 9):

1. Open Terminal
2. Run **setup.py**
3. Run **source /Users/your_user/.profile** (so that environment variables are actually updated)
4. Run **cocos new mygame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d /directory_to_your_game**

Comment: cocos new my game **-p** com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d /directory_to_your_game

Answer (score 3):

1. run the setup.py (I had problem with python 3.X, so i switched back to python 2.7.6)
2. open cmd and run the command **cocos new MyGame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d /home**

cd ~/home ... you will find your new project.

Comment: For cocos2d-x 3.0beta2, the way to create a project is exactly what you say. However, 3.0rc version which released on Mar 15th seems to have totally changed it.@sunny 1304

Comment: @Dong sorry dude, i have updated the answer, i should be more careful.